# how to insert custom images and html in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I'm creating a new WordPress Theme and I want a *media* folder to contain some images that are not considered to be posts.

e.g. *themes/theme-name/media/sampleIMG.jpg*

adding

```
<img src="media/sampleIMG.jpg">
```

in my theme folders index.php leads to an 404 error code output because apparently my local apache server is requesting that file from a different directory:

*/html/media/sampleIMG.jpg*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="" class="svg logo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **get_template_directory_uri()** to link a static image with its correct path in html :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/media/sampleIMG.jpg"  alt="theme logo" />
```

> Note: **get_template_directory_uri()** return absolute path to the
>   directory of the current theme.